# SKAction playSoundFileNamed Not Playing Sound on Physical iPad

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently on Whack-A-Penguin (Project 14) of Hacking with Swift. I am trying to get the sound to work, but I am unsure of why it is not working. There is no error code that comes up in debugger, which makes it hard to understand what is going wrong...

I am testing on a physical iPad with the sound settings on. Below is a snapshot of where i have placed the files and how the soundfile is being called in my code. Not sure what the issue is...Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Image of my file directory and code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boN5u.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you select your sound file in XCode, access the inspector on the right side, then make sure the file is selected for your target(s).

[Screenshot from Xcode showing where to do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Lq6y.png)